# How do I find KKT Conditions for the Quadratic Function?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am trying to understand how to find the KKT conditions for the general Quadratic Programming problem, in vector form. Following [Cornujoels & Tütüncü](http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/CT_FinOpt.pdf) (7.1), this is written:

$$\min_x \frac{1}{2}\, \underline{x}^T Q\, \underline{x} + c^T 
\underline{x}$$
$$s.t.  \;A  \underline{x} = \underline{b}$$
$$\qquad  \underline{x} \geq 0$$

I believe the first optimality condition is that the gradient of the Lagrangian $ (\mathcal{\nabla L})$ will be equal to zero, where:

$$
\mathcal{L}(\underline{x},\lambda) = 
\frac{1}{2} \underline{x}^T Q \,\underline{x} + c^T \underline{x} - \lambda \,(\underline{b}-A \underline{x} )$$

but I am not entirely sure how to actually perform the differentiation given that the Lagrangian appears to be a matrix; are we looking for the Jacobian?

In the textbook, equation 7.3 gives the first KKT condition to be:
$$ A^T \underline{y} - Q \underline{x} + \underline{s} = \underline{c} $$
which I simply can't follow. It seems to be using the variables $y, s$ from the dual problem (7.2), but I'm not sure why, or why there appears to be a slack variable $s$.

Am I wrong to think I should be differentiating the Lagrangian of the primal problem, and if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lagrangian is
$$L(x, y, s) = \frac{1}{2} x^\top Q x + c^\top x + y^\top (b-Ax) - s^\top x$$
with $s \succeq 0$.

Taking the gradient yields
$$Qx + c - A^\top y - s.$$
(Note that you copied down the KKT condition incorrectly.)

Comment: Thanks - I've corrected the equation. I see how you took the gradient, which visually looks like treating the vectors like scalars but I realise now (of course) that $x^T Q x$ is in fact a sum of scalars, as are the other terms. However, I don't see how you have calculated the Lagrangian? (Note: I was following (12.16) from Nocedal & Wright http://www.xn--vjq503akpco3w.top/literature/Nocedal_Wright_Numerical_optimization_v2.pdf)

Comment: @Zac Maybe look at [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Multiple_constraints) of a Wikipedia page. Basically the constraints $Ax=b$ and $x \ge 0$ are a sequence of one-dimensional constraints $a_i^\top x = b$ and $x_j \ge 0$, so if you get a Lagrange multiplier for each constraint. The sums on the Wikipedia page can be condensed using matrix notation, so the vectors $y$ and $s$ are vectors of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Ah excellent. The vector notation had me confused but that makes sense! And I guess I had missed that the non-negativity constraints needed to be included in the Lagrangian too. Putting those together and I get the same answer, thank you.