# Why is there an extra equality constraint in the optimality conditions for a quadratic programming problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I know that for an equality-constrained optimization problems the optimality conditions are that the gradient must be orthogonal to the constraint vectors.

So, say we have a problem like this:

$$\min_x \frac{1}{2}\, x^T Q\, x + c^T 
x$$
$$s.t.  \;A  x = b$$

since [edited] $\nabla f = Qx+c$, the optimality condition is $\nabla f = Qx+c \in \{v|A^Tw=v\},$ for some $w\in \mathbb{R}^n$, which can be said like so:  $Qx+c = A^Tw$.

But, according to resources like this one, https://ee227c.github.io/notes/ee227c-lecture13.pdf, there is an additional constraint, which is that the minimizer lies in the affine set described by the equality constraint: $Ax=b$

I don't see how this constraint comes about from the FONC of optimality.  What is it about the FONC that give rise satisifying $Ax=b$?  Isn't that taken care of by the gradient being orthogonal to the constraint vectors by saying $Qx+c = A^Tw$?  or no?

related: [How do I find KKT Conditions for the Quadratic Function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694224/how-do-i-find-kkt-conditions-for-the-quadratic-function?rq=1)

Comment: I dont get it. Whats a quadratic programming problem?  Maybe Im ignorant but that seems to me to be a linear programming problem. Also some of what youre talking about is over my head. But I say it an LP problem as the constraints are linear, therefore the optimum is either at a vertex of the feasible region (found using standard LP) or its in the middle of the feasible region, which you can find with standard calculus techniques.  The optimum, if in the feasible region, is at the solution to $x = -(Q^T)^{-1}c$.

Comment: Quadratic programming: "Quadratic programming (QP) is the process of solving a special type of mathematical optimization problem—specifically, a (linearly constrained) quadratic optimization problem, that is, the problem of optimizing (minimizing or maximizing) a quadratic function of several variables subject to linear constraints on these variables. Quadratic programming is a particular type of nonlinear programming."

Comment: The gradient is $\nabla f = Qx+c$. The factor $\frac{1}{2}$ is dropped.

Comment: Before you check the solution is optimal, it had better be feasible, isn't that the point?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum this seems like one of those cases where a simple Google search could have saved you some embarrassment. QP is a very well known class of optimization problems, and it is certainly not the same as LP.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek is correct. $Ax=b$ is just the primary feasibility condition. Obviously it must be satisfied at the optimum, along with $Qx+c=A^Tw$, which is the _dual_ feasibility condition.

Comment: OKay thanks @MichaelGrant.  So, if $Ax=b$ is the primal feasibility condition, and $Qx+c=A^Tw$ is the *dual* feasibility condition?  Then it seems like we are ONLY concerned with feasibility?  Where in this are we concerned with the more general condition that the directional gradient be in the normal cone?

Comment: The KKT conditions do not concern themselves with that. Primal feasibility, dual feasibility, and complementary slackness, that's it. A primal/dual pair that satisfies all three is optimal.

Comment: @MichaelGrant,  there's also lagrangian optimality.  the gradient of the lagrangian must also be 0.  that is the 4th KKT condition.  The KKT conditions are just an alternative way to get a stationary point (which is a point that satisfies the FONC of optimality), similar to the optimality conditions like "gradient must be orthogonal to the tangent cone in all directions for x to be locally optimal".  but the KKT conditions are certainly not the only way to get a stationary point - but if the dual is easily accessible, then the KKT conditions are certainly convenient.