# How does complementary slackness come from the optimality conditions of a penalty/barrier method?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I’m trying to understand how complementary slackness arises from the optimality conditions of a penalty/barrier method.

I have the following problem:

$$\min_x \{\frac{1}{2} x^T Q x + c^T x – t \sum\limits_{i=1}^n log(y_i) \}\,\,\,  
s.t. Ax+y=b $$

$Q \in \mathbb{S}^{nxn}_{++}\, c \in \mathbb{R}^n\, A \in \mathbb{R}^{m x n} \, b \in \mathbb{R}^{m} $

I know that the optimality conditions are that the gradient must be orthogonal to the constrained region, which means $-\nabla f \in R(A^T)$ or $\nabla f = A^T w$ for some $w \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

I want to somehow show that the optimality condition $-\nabla f \in R(A^T)$ gives rise to the condition, $w_i*y_i=0\,\, \forall i\,\,$.

I think it has something to do with complementary slackness, but I am not sure.  I know intuitively that $w_i*y_i=0\,\, \forall i\,\,$ must be true at any FONC (stationary) point.  But I do not understand how it comes from optimality conditions.

How does it come from optimality conditions?

I understand how to do it generally for the quadratic function: [How do I find KKT Conditions for the Quadratic Function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694224/how-do-i-find-kkt-conditions-for-the-quadratic-function)

Comment: You will have $w_i y_i = 1/t \to 0$ in the KKT conditions of your barrier problem.

Comment: yes, but how?  I cannot derive that for some reason.

Comment: you'll have to be more specific than "I cannot derive that"